# Can't find method Shiny.IShinyStartup.ConfigureServices with Prism 8

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

The error I'm getting during app startup is the following:

> Parent class vtable failed to initialize, due to: Could not load list of method overrides due to Method not found: void Shiny.IShinyStartup.ConfigureServices(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection) assembly:/Users/merickson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D19E269D-A3E5-46C2-BB9C-94A122EA02DC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F9A34529-8F64-4868-8D7F-389C77DB54BC/PrismSizeTest.iOS.app/Shiny.Prism.dll type:PrismStartup member:(null)

I'm not sure if I'm missing a NuGet, maybe wrong version of one or more NuGets, or am I initializing something wrong?  Any help is appreciated.

I've been able to replicate this with a bare bones solution which I can provide if necessary.  Here are the main files involved:

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : PrismApplicationBase
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer)
        : base(initializer)
    {
    }

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppInfo, AppInfoImplementation>();

        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
    }

    protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension() => ContainerLocator.Current;
}
```

AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        ShinyHost.Init(new ApplePlatform(), new MyStartup());

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}

public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        // Register any platform specific implementations
    }
}
```

MyStartup.cs

```
public class MyStartup : PrismStartup
{
    protected override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.UseGps<GpsDelegate>();
    }
}
```

NuGets installed:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing directly wrong with the code... however the latest versions of Shiny have breaking ABI changes that make Shiny.Prism and Shiny.Core incompatible which is the result of the issue shown here...

For more information you can track the issue at: https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions/issues/183